# Dictionary and hyphenation not working in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, hyphenation, dictionaries

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I've just updated my TeXstudio to version 2.12.10.

While the previous version (around 2.8) used to check spelling and did the hyphenation correctly, now it does not work at all.

What I've tried:

- download the OpenOffice '.oxt' dictionary and install (via the button) it in Settings of TeXStudio (once directly from 'Downloads' registry, once moved it - with `sudo` permission - to `/usr/share/` directory and)
- adding `/usr/share/hunspell`, where I found the correct `cs_cZ.aff` and `cs_cZ.dic` files, to paths in "Preferences -> Language Checking" and "Preferences -> Spelling Dictionary Directories"
  [image]
- I haven't found out, what `.dat` file I could put into the "Slovníková databáze" (= "Dictionary database") line
- always restarted TeXstudio after each change.
- interesting behaviour: a word is underlined iff it contains czech diacritic, when clicking on it with right-button, either the word is (despite being very common word) not in the dictionary or it appears wrongly encoded
- so I tried changing the encoding of `.aff` and `.dic` file from the original ISO 8859-2 into UTF-8, but no effect.

Any idea what to try next?

Comment: TXS seems to have recognized the `cs_CZ` dictionary that you have in the hunspell folder (you have it selected in "Vychozi jazyk"). Where did you download the `.oxt` from?

Comment: @Troy I downloaded it from https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/dict-cs.

Comment: Works fine here. When you say it does not work, what exactly does that mean? Czech words are marked by TeXstudio as wrong spelling? Or...? What language dictionary is TeXstudio using to check in that case? (Right click on a "wrongly spelt" Czech word in your document: what spelling suggestions pop up?)

Comment: Exactly - most of czech words (even common, non-math) are marked red. The suggestion is either non-existing ("Add to dictionary" even for common words) or incorrectly coded (aha!?). However, now, when I look at marked words, those are underlined iff they contain czech diacritic! So maybe some coding error in dictionaries?

Comment: If the dictionary that you are using is the one you provided above, I don't think there is an error in the dictionary (it seems to work fine as far as I can tell. This gave no spelling mistakes on mine: "Jsem velmi potěšen, že vás poznávám".) Do the other dictionaries work fine? e.g. `en_GB`?

Comment: They do (funny fact: "spelt" exists in `en_GB`, but not in `en_US`).

Comment: Can you try putting the `cs_CZ.dic` and `cs_CZ.aff` files into the same directory (folder) where `en_GB.dic` is? i.e. the TeXstudio default dictionaries folder. and maybe restart TeXstudio just for good measure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80571/discussion-between-pepa-dvorak-and-troy).

Comment: @Troy Solved, finally!

Answer (score 1):

Download `Czech.dic` and `Czech.aff` from https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries, rename to `cs_CZ.dic` and `cs_CZ.aff`, link texstudio to them and you're done - the issue is really in encoding; seems it cannot be solved by mere re-encoding original files into `utf-8`.